# Is ODBC / Win7 64-bit / Excel 2010 64-bit limited to 255 columns?

Tags: windows-7, odbc, excel-2007, excel-2010, wow64

I'm using ODBC to write to an XLSB file.  Am I limited to 255 columns (or somewhere close to that)?  When I try to write 500 columns I get the following error:

```
HY001 -1040 [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too many fields defined.
```

Perhaps I have the wrong drivers?  Here's my connection string:

```
"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};Dbq=PATH_TO_XLSB_HERE;DefaultDir=OUTPUT_FOLDER_HERE;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel 2010 itself supports 16,384 columns:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291

You probably need to switch to the ACE.OLEDB ODBC provider to take advantage of them, though.

Comment: This is the Access driver right?  that can be used for Excel?

Comment: That's right.  And text files, too.  It can handle the same types as the old Jet driver, but also newer versions.

Comment: Does this require me to register a system or user DSN?  or can I just specify the driver/file I'm trying to connect to and it will work out?

Comment: No need to register a DSN, you can set it all in the connection string similar to how you've been trying it.  Unfortunately, I don't have an example handy.